# Image field input renders with type text instead of file

Tags: 7, media

(Drupal newb - please go easy and give references that help me learn how to debug stuff in Drupal myself, thank you!)

I've taken over a Drupal site with 7.80.

There's a type called Event which has a bunch of fields including an Image. There are many existing Events where Image upload presumably worked fine in the past. The images are visible when editing those Events.

**Problem: The form for adding a new Event renders the Image control as a text box (i.e. `input type='text'` with an attach button instead of a file control (i.e. `input type='file'`).**

Also notable that if I use e.g. chrome inspector to change the type of the input to file and then try to upload a file it fails with:

"The file in the Image field was unable to be uploaded."

How can I start to debug this? Google didn't turn up any obvious hits that I could find so pointers on how to start debugging much appreciated!

Comment: Check which widget is being used for that field (in Manage Fields), it might be something custom the previous developers have written

Comment: Regarding: _"Also notable that if I use e.g. chrome inspector to change the type of the input to file and then try to upload a file it fails with:

"The file in the Image field was unable to be uploaded."_ That is reassuring, as it would constitute a [Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).